# How to give custom name to Mailing letter in MS Word/Excel and save it?

Tags: excel, ms-word, letter, mailing

I've been searching about this without success. I'm trying to generate different MS Word documents from a table in Excel. All settings seems to work fine but each document is generated with name "Letter1", "Letter2", ..., "LetterN" and are not still saved. I need to go to over each one and give the desired name to finally save it.

Is there a way to automatically give custom name to each letter taking the name from a field in the same MS Excel table and be saved it automatically in custom path?  Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't told us anything about *how* these letters are being generated. Assuming it's via mailmerge, see *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* and/or
*Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Thanks for the information shared. And yes, I'm using the feature Mail merge in menu "Mailing" having added a recipient list from a Excel sheet. I see it can be done using VBA. I'll try the examples in the link you shared hoping to get my goal. Regards